# Firebase .where() queries

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query my Firestore database to get documents which satisfy 2 conditions.

Using the code below, my snapshot returns an error.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> bags = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('bags')
    .where("station", isEqualTo: currentlySelectedStation)
    .where('lastMonthlyChecked', isNotEqualTo: currentMonth)
    .snapshots();
```

if I delete either one of the .where() queries, the other one returns as expected and populates a listview.

What could be the reason that having 2 .where() queries causes an error?

Answer (score 1):

Every query you execute on Firestore requires that you have the right [indexes for that query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#an_index_behind_every_query).

Firestore auto-creates an index for each individual field, which explains why your query on a single field already works. But when you add a second field to the query, it requires a so-called [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#queries_supported_by_composite_indexes) - and those are not automatically created.

Catch the error that is thrown by your code, log it, and check for the URL in there. If you open that URL, you're taken to a page in the Firestore console that allows you to create the index with a single click (and a bit of patience).

Also see the Firestore documentation on [creating additional indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing)